# Windows 10 Installation Setup Not Starting After USB Boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bootable-media

The Problem: After booting from a USB device with correct BIOS configurations, the Windows 10 (with Microsoft's official tool) or OEM logo (with all other methods) will only show for a few seconds. Then the PC restarts and keeps rebooting after reaching the OEM screen. The PC needs to load the setup screen so that I can reinstall the OS on a currently Ubuntu (Linux) system that initially ran Windows 10.

Context: For creating a functional USB boot, I have used Microsoft's media creation tool, Rufus, WoeUSB, UNetbootin, and simply copying the files from the mounted ISO. For each method, I also tried switching Secure Boot and UEFI / Legacy boot orders in the BIOS, partitioning the drive with either FAT32 or NTFS, and formatting the drive with either MBR or GPT. Every trial has failed, even though the ISO downloaded can run Windows 10 via VirtualBox and the PC can boot other OSs. GRUB, which is the boot loader that powers the PC's Ubuntu OS, might be interfering. However, that would not explain how the PC can reach the Windows 10 logo and then the boot fails.

I have looked through posts on this topic on SuperUser alongside other websites, but I cannot find the right solution. The PC can and has run Windows 10 in the past, and even if I can just get a dual boot installation on my USB-connected SSD drive I would be satisfied for my workflow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Additional Information:

a) Windows 10 ISO Version (Intended OS to boot): 21H2

b) Ubuntu Version (OS currently on PC): 22.04 LTS

c) OEM: HP

Comment: Might there be a problem with the computer? What happened that requires a reinstallation?

Comment: I need to run certain programs that only run on Windows, and VM software is not efficient while Wine is incompatible. I originally switched from Windows 10 to Linux on my PC because back then I did not need to use applications like Solidworks or Visual Studio.

Comment: Can the computer boot a Linux Live USB?

Comment: @Matt It sounds like InstallUSB [WinPE] is incorrectly configured or the UEFI firmware is incorrectly configured, as the PC isn't booting the install USB [WinPE] since "_...the Windows 10 (with Microsoft's official tool) or OEM logo..._" implies the Windows OS bootloader/UEFI firmware screen is being shown. **[CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) should _never_ be enabled**, as it's sole purpose was to support BSD/Linux distros that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017 _(Windows has supported EFI boot since Win7)_.

Comment: @Matt _(Cont'd...)_ Disable CSM Mode and recreate the WinPE InstallUSB with Rufus using the ISO downloaded via the Media Creation Tool _(or use the Media Creation Tool to create a bootable USB)_. This is an either/or situation, as it can only be one of three things - (1) CSM Mode is enabled _(it should not be)_; (2) The WinPE InstallUSB was incorrectly created; and/or (3) USB booting is disabled in the UEFI firmware. General FYI: if the USB drive is MBR, the partition must be marked `Active`, whereas if it's GPT, it simply needs the Windows install ISO extracted to it in order to boot it.

Comment: @Matt If you're formatting the drive as NTFS, the motherboard's UEFI firmware must have an NTFS driver, and even then WinPE won't correctly load without additional drivers being manually injected into it's `boot.wim` - FAT32 is recommended.

Comment: @JW0914 I booted a Rufus-created drive with CSM disabled and USB booting enabled, as a GPT. I also gave the Media Creation Tool another shot. Both attempts did not succeed. If was WinPE was incorrectly created, how can I solve this? Additionally, if the ISO is bigger than 4gb wouldn't FAT32 always fail? Thank you for your help.

Comment: FAT32 has a 4GB _file_ size limit - no file in the Windows install ISO from the Media Creation Tool is over >4GB _(the `install.esd` is always <4GB, whereas an `install.wim` will be >4GB)_. When using Rufus, are any settings being changed _([example](https://imgur.com/a/Afez9Tj))_? It's going to be impossible for anyone to reproduce your issue, so what will likely be required are screenshots of what's being done to create the InstallUSB from start to finish, output of `ls -AFhpR /mnt/<usbdrive>`, and a photo of the Windows bootloader screen once UEFI hands off to it (when OEM logo disappears)